# MySQL search for words in any or specific order (multiple possibilities) - Best approach?

Tags: mysql, regex, database, search, full-text-search

I have a MySQL database with one column and many rows which are filled
with sentences. I want to make a search which will take user input
(which could be 1 or more words separated by space) to find sentences
which contains words in specific order like this:

**User input:**  `Word1` `Word2`

Search options:

1. Find sentences which contain this 2 words in any order and any
   place
2. Find sentences which contain `Word1` in the first place, and
   `Word2` in any place, but not just after `Word1` (minimum 1 word in
   between)
3. Find sentences which contain `Word1` in the first place, and
   `Word2` just after it.
4. Find sentences which contain `Word1` on any place (not first) and
   `Word2` on any place, but not just after `Word1` (minimum 1 word in
   between)
5. Find sentences which contain `Word1` in any place (not first) and
   `Word2` just after it.

Also, there could be more than 2 words in search with this rules
combined to find a specific pattern.

On one website I saw a solution for similar search when users use
special signs in search field to find patterns they want. For example:
`X + Y` (one word followed immediately by another), `X - Y` (one word
followed by other, immediately or with some number of words in
between), `X Y` (any order of words)...

Any suggestions how to approach this problem? I read a lot about Regex
or FullText search, but I don't know where to start and what is the
best solution. What is the best and fast search for this kind of
problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not a complete answer, but I think you are looking for a search DSL (search domain specific language).  ElasticSearch might be a good place to start.  Converting your `Word + Word` or `Word - Word` to ElasticSearch expressions using RegExp would be relatively simple.  There may be alternatives to ElasticSearch which even provide simple search input rules like this.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I checked some texts about Elasticsearch but it is bit complicated for me to cross over from MySQL to ES. I just started learning MySQL and PHP and started to take a grip with it. Is there any possibility to give me advice how to approach this problem with MySQL and PHP? That would be very appreciated.

Comment: Honestly you will be better off using an off the peg solution like elasticsearch to reduce complexity.   While you may be feeling swamped already with MySQL and PHP you will be better off not having to build and maintain your own search library.  There might be a PHP search library that you can find, I don't know what is going on in PHP for about 15 years, so I can't help with that.   You could definitely try to create each of your 5 search rules, in PHP.  but you will first need to define exactly what you expect the user to enter as a search term for each of those rules beforehand.

Comment: As ocodo said, a specialized engine is your best option. You can use a fulltext search, but have to implement yourself what it does not support on its own. Use the fulltext search (you do not need it, but it might be faster), then check if the rest of your condition is fulfilled (e.g. `and column like = "% word1 % word2 %" ` for 4). This requires clean data, e.g. that your words are seperated by exactly 1 space, and not `,` or something, otherwise the test gets more complicated). You may also need to define what happens if words occur twice (e.g. word1 at the start and the middle).

Comment: A more general remark: are you sure you want such specialized search options? In the year 2018, it makes for a very weird (=uncommon) user experience if the user has to choose with such a precision what he wants to search for (look at how siri/google are used). You may want to order the results w.r.t your conditions (e.g. if the sentence starts with word1, weight it heigher than if it is at the end). Although, for this, elasticsearch/solr/... are again better equipped. If your user is not an end user, this might be a different situation.

Comment: Actually, it is must be precise as that because the search results depend on the precision. I called these entries in database a words for better understanding, but they are actually a codes for special language symbols (which make up words when combined) organized in database like this: I9 - G1 - A9 - R4 - X1 - Q3 - X1 - X4 - Z2, or O1 - D21 - X1 - D54 - G17 - O4 - D21 - Z7 - N5 - Z1 - V12 - Z1, so the users can search by following sequence with any 2 or more of symbols to finda a perfect match(es). If the only option for such complex search is ElasticSearch or SORL, then I must do by it.

Comment: In this case, the proper data model might be to add a table with one "word"/code per row (so a table with something like `(id, pos, code)`). A fulltext index is used in cases this is not possible (as e.g. storing "normal" text this way is oftentimes not usefull). Whatever query you write is basically recreating that structure on the fly (getting/checking the posititions from your collapsed string) and not indexable. Using this model might not be possible in your situation (I do not know your app and the rest of your requirements), but this design would solve this specific problem more easily.

Comment: I succeeded to write a small search code in PHP & MySQL which uses user input (e.g. X1 Q3) and get me all rows which contain X1 or Q3 and all rows which contain both. Now I have a problem how to write PHP script which could detect other search paterns which user defines in the search field (e.g. X1 + Q3, and he gets all rows which contain only both symbols, not one or another).

Comment: Here is my script (corrected by other users): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655637/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-error-what-is-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have a `FULLTEXT` index on the column.
- Construct `MATCH(col) AGAINST('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` as the primary filter.
- Construct `AND col RLIKE ...` or other things -- when you have more constraints.

Here's the logic:

- When `MATCH` is part of the `WHERE` clause, it will be run first because it is quite efficient.
- `+` in `AGAINST` means a required word.
- That will filter down to a few rows, namely the rows with all those words.
- Then the other clauses (which will be expensive to run) will not be too costly because they will be hitting only a few rows.

  1. (words anywhere)  no extra clause needed.
  2. (ordered, but not adjacent):  `col RLIKE '[[:<:]]word1[[:>:]].*[[:alpha:]].*[[:<:]]word2[[:>:]]'`
  3. (start, adjacent, in a certain order:  `col RLIKE '^word1[[:>:]] [[:<:]]word2[[:>:]]'` (assumes a single space between the words)
  4. (ambiguous; ordering unclear) -- is a combination of two of the other cases.
  5. (adjacent, in a certain order:  `col RLIKE '[[:<:]]word1 word2[[:>:]]'` (assumes a single space between the words)

Regexp notes:

- `[[:<:]]` means start of word
- `^` (when first) means start of string
- `.*[[:alpha:]].*` matches any string that has at least one letter

Comment: Thank you for these solutions. They will be very helpful. Is there any chance that you now how to convert user input like this: word1 + word2, into 5. solution from your list, with PHP to MySQL - for code to understand + sign as rule for one word adjacent to another?

Comment: I made a couple of changes.  As for interpreting `+` as input to PHP -- that's a parsing problem in PHP; I am addressing only the MySQL issues.  See `preg_match('/^(\w+) ?[+] ?(\w+)$/', $inp, $m)` -- if that matches, then `$m[1]` contains "word1" and `$m[2]` contains "word2" and it is option 5.

Comment: Thank you for help. I hope that these solutions will solve most of my needs.